# How to use the named parameters with CONTAINS

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanna use the named parameters with CONTAINS like that :

```
select p from person p
where CONTAINS(p.name , :myName)

String myName = "Bob Jones";
q.setString("myName", "*" + myName + "*");
```

It doesn't work, the error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Erreur de syntaxe près de 'Jones*' dans la condition de recherche en texte intégral '*Bob Jones*'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:778)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 8 more
```

I use hibernate 3.6
What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: q.setString("myName", myName+"%");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using SQL Server. Then your query contains a problem that has nothing to do with Hibernate or Java. It's just about the syntax of the CONTAINS operator. Just try it with any tool that can directly query the database.

If you want to query for two words, the syntax is either of the following:

```
select * from person where contains(name, 'Bob AND Jones');
select * from person where contains(name, 'Bob OR Jones');
select * from person where contains(name, '"Bob Jones"');
```

If you additionally want to query for prefixes, it's:

```
select * from person where contains(name, 'Bob* AND Jones*');
select * from person where contains(name, 'Bob* OR Jones*');
select * from person where contains(name, '"Bob Jones*"');
```

You cannot put the asterisk in front of a word or phrase.

I recommend you have a look at the description of the [CONTAINS operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

**Update:**

Thanks for your comment. If you look at your old code, you'll note the extra pair of double quotes that enclosed the second argument to CONTAINS, similar to my third and last example. That's what's missing in your current code. So to fix it:

```
String myName = "Bob Jones";
q.setString("myName", "\"*" + myName + "*\"");
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.
I'm using SQL Server.
The old query seems like that :

String myName = "Bob Jones";

select p from person p
where CONTAINS(p.name , '\"*" + myName + "*\"')

It works, but I have to use the named parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @user1940268: Using bound parameters to prevent SQL injections is a very good thing to do. Please have a look at my updated answer. I think you're just missing a pair of double quotes.

Comment: your update fixes my problem. thank U.
My last answer is another problem.

Comment: @user1940268: If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. It's important feedback for to the user's of StackOverflow as it indicates which answers were useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using like instead of contains.

```
from Person p where p.name like :myName
```

Then when you execute the query

```
List<User> userList = query.setParameter("myName", "%" + name+ "%").list();
```

Comment: Thx but I have to use CONTAINS