# A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use

Tags: java, hibernate

I post a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106239/how-to-use-the-named-parameters-with-contains)
I this error appears after running the hibernate query and I don't know what does it mean.
So I rerun the query few minutes later, then I haven't the error but I wanna know how I get it and how to fix it.

```
WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.checkOpen(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1713)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.clearWarnings(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2020)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.clearWarnings(NewProxyConnection.java:933)
    at org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.handleAndClearWarnings(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logAndClearWarnings(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterStatement(ConnectionManager.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1053)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:465)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:778)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:842)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:723)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:466)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:103)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.peek(ResponseStream.java:88)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.wait(TdsCore.java:3932)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1046)
    ... 16 more
```

**Update :**

My first code :

```
Session session = getSessionfactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

ArrayList<Object[]> results = null;
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select p from person p ");
    sb.append("where CONTAINS(p.name , :myName) ");

    Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
    String myName = "Bob Jones";
    q.setString("myName", "*" + myName + "*");  

    results = (ArrayList<Object[]>) q.list();

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error : ", e);
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

It doesn't work, [to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106239/how-to-use-the-named-parameters-with-contains)
this is the 2nd version :

```
Session session = getSessionfactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

ArrayList<Object[]> results = null;
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select p from person p ");
    sb.append("where CONTAINS(p.name , :myName) ");

    Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
    String myName = "Bob Jones";
    q.setString("myName", "\"*" + myName + "*\""); 

    results = (ArrayList<Object[]>) q.list();

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error : ", e);
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Trying to run the 2nd version, I have the error above.

Answer (score 10):

Your transaction-management and/or connection-management code is probably off. It seems that you are not releasing the connection to the connection pool after an error, and trying to reuse it. This may be due to a wrong exception-handling idiom you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't understand what do you mean in " you are not releasing the connection to the connection pool after an error, and trying to reuse it". Can you explain what should I do?

Comment: I can't help you without seeing your code, especially the connection acquisition/transaction management part.

Comment: Hello,
Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: This error appears randomly and I have to fix it up. I read many forums but I can't solve it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am having this same error. I grab a session, a new one if none exists, then session.getTransaction(); if there is not already an active, i use beginTransaction on it. this is when this happens. I commit the transactions before. For me it works to populate a hundred times but then I run into this, likely due to connecition pool running out. I am not sure how to return it to pool, since it is configured by c3p0 with hibernate properties. all i do is sessionFactory().getSession().getTransaction()

Answer (score 1):

By using jTDS you are probably trying to connect to MS SQL or Sybase.  Based on the code you posted everything looks fine.  I suggests you look to upgrading your driver and raising your logging level for more detail logs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I use jTDS 1.2.4 with MS SQL 2008.
Is it possible that this version of jTDS doesn't support the query named parameter?

Comment: I try to upgrade the jTDS version to 1.2.7 and after to 1.3.0, but that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: If there is an error in a sqlQuery, does c3p0 remember or keep it anyway? or is there a code to "clean" the c3p0 pooledConnection?
because when I tested the query, I'd error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106239/how-to-use-the-named-parameters-with-contains)

Comment: How to detect what close the object connection? or what's the connection error?

Answer (score 0):

To add my 2 cent, It seems that there is some issue with network connectivity with Database.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused
>   connection abort: recv failed

Also try to test with another DB, so that to check if DB could be the cause of randomly occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens if your pool idle timeout (checking connection with test query) runs before the database connection timeout (not hearing anything from client), i.e., the DB server decides to drop and client is not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using suggested indexes by native database tools, it is probably due to all other connections are taking time to fetch response from table and no new connections can be made, hence connection is closed warning.